# How do I change Code::Blocks language to english

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks

I own a used computer that used to be set to Korean and would replace "backslash" with the symbol for Korean money in the command prompt. I downloaded Code::Blocks before i fixed this problem, but now it is still replacing backslash for some reason.

I tried to change the encoding settings, which were set to korean but that didn't work. I have also tried to reinstall it.

All questions I found relating to this simply say to not use any language other than english to program in, but I'm trying to get everything to be english, so its frustrating.

Comment: Maybe remove/reinstall with the Korean unset?

Comment: Check the language set for **Current language for non-Unicode programs** in Control Panel -> Region -> Administrative tab. Change it to English if it isn't already.

Comment: Which operating system? Does the replacement occur when typing in the Code::Blocks editor or when running a terminal program (or both)? At a high level, what did you do to fix the problem in the command prompt? (E.g., Did it involve setting a new keyboard layout?)

Comment: It used to occur on both, but I've fixed the terminal by changing the region in the control panel, and now it only occurs in the Code::Blocks editor.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this go to settings>editor>general settings>encoding settings and change encoding language.  This will not change any files already set to korean so create a new file.